# Dynamic Table of Contents using Puppeteer for PDF

Tags: css, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I've been looking around for a solution to this, most answers are simply that it's not possible. I've seen that Paged.js (considered using it, but it seemed too big and off purpose) manage to use

`a::after { content: target-counter(attr(href), page, decimal); }`

, changing the content there to fill in correct page numbers for the ToC. I'm guessing this means they have created a css-polyfill that fixes this in their library? It doesn't seem like browsers support target-counter and ::after. I am not sure if I am correct in my thinking here - but I went looking for a css polyfill to make target-counter work for me as well (and page-break-after: avoid), since paged.js seem to be doing it in this way.

Anyway, the second option I've been looking at is using a PDF parser to parse through all the data in the pdf, and somehow use regexes and loops and other hacky stuff to find the page numbers of the elements I am looking for. Maybe I would put the parser return value into a JSON file and fetch that JSON file from the table of contents or something? Sounds slow, since I'll also have to merge the pdf one more time. (Doing it once already for the frontpage)

To be a little specific: I would like to know whether one or both of these solutions are possible, and if they are, I'd love some pointers on A. a polyfill that fixes the CSS-tags I need, or B. an idea/way to sort and structure the data from the pdf-parser.

Comment: For what it's worth, [this issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1778) tracks this feature request for Puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

For option B, below script will be a good start for anyone interested.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const pdf = require('pdf-parse');
const { Readable } = require("stream");
let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('./generated.pdf');
pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data) {
    let toc ={}, page;
    const pagePattern = /Page [0-9]+\/[0-9]+/;
    const topicPattern = /Title: [A-Za-z 0-9]+/;
    const lines = data.text.split('\n');
    lines.forEach((chunk, i, lines) => {
        if(chunk.match(pagePattern)) {
            page = chunk
        }
        if(chunk.match(topicPattern) && !toc[chunk]) {
            toc[chunk] = page
        }
    });
    console.log(toc); // Use this object to fill in values for your table of content
});
```

Hope this will help someone.